# Symfony framework on windows azure cloud

Tags: windows, symfony1, azure, cloud

is it possible to run symfony (1.4) on the windows azure cloud?
The two things I'm wondering is how to execute the symfony tasks and where will symfony save the cache files (blob storage?).

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is something that Microsoft are taking very seriously these days so yes, Symfony can run on top of Azure although documentation is sparse as most people stick to Linux servers.

Regarding tasks, there is a tool for running command line tasks on Windows Azure although I have not yet tried it myself.

http://azurephptools.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time I got symfony 1.4 running inside the WindowsAzure Cloud. It was not as hard as expected. I was also able to write a blob storage caching for symfony. Session handling works ok, but you need to modify the symfony session handler to work correctly with more than one server instances.

Comment: i'm having problem with sessions, can you explain me how to configure symfony session handling for several instances?